# reading span text

Tags: jquery

I have a div in which I have spans and I want to read all the text of the inner span.  I am not able to read the span "name" text.  What is wrong with the following piece of code?

```
<div id= "myList">
<span class="FirstSpan">
<span class = "name">

</span>

</span>

</div>

 var values= [];
        $('#myList').find('span.name').each(function () {
            $alert($(this).html());
            values.push($(this).html());
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$alert()` should be `alert()`

you can try

```
$(this).text()
```

***Full code***

```
var values = [];
$('#myList span.name').each(function () {
     alert($(this).text());
     values.push($(this).text());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zkTud/12/)**

Other way:

```
var values = [];
$('#myList span.name').text(function(i, text) {
    alert(text);
    values.push(text);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zkTud/11/)**

**Related refs:**

- **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each)**
- **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text)**

Comment: Just to add further :) http://jsfiddle.net/bY4EV/7/ as you nailed it anyways `:P`

Answer (score 1):

There is no function `$alert()` and that is the problem. Use [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.alert) instead.

However, in your case I'd better use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method:

```
var values = $("#myList span.name").map(function() {
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML);
}).get();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/m5QsA/